# How do I synchronize data between high-speed thread by thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

there was an error during data communication, so I'm asking you a similar example.

The following example consists of send threads and receive threads:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t1 = new Thread(() => SendProc());
        t2 = new Thread(() => ReceiveProc());

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }


    private void SendProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            buf = val.ToString();
            ++val;

            this.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text = val.ToString() + "\n" + this.richTextBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = (++cnt1).ToString();
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(SEND_TIME_INTERVAL);
        }

    }



    private void ReceiveProc()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buf))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(RECEIVE_TIME_INTERVAL);
                continue;
            }

            this.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                this.richTextBox2.Text = val.ToString() + "\n" + this.richTextBox2.Text;
                textBox2.Text = (++cnt2).ToString();
            }));

            buf = "";
        }
    }
```

[Left : Send   Right : Receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZVr.png)

Strangely, the send data and receive data are not synchronized.

Send proc must be sleep for 3 seconds.

The example source code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqTyWdLViWw-glFztzYVoLah1egcZU7g/view?usp=sharing

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll need to use an event, a mutex, or similar. Also, the invokes will sync to the UI thread (as you probably know) - that will put a significant cap on your potential throughput. It's better to use a buffer to queue up stuff for the UI and only do invoke every once in a while.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you. The key is to use event and mutex! Unfortunately I don't have any idea what to do with my lack of skills... Do you have any sites to refer to? And the result is similar even if i printed Log without using Invoke method.

Comment: You'll have to work on your google skills :) I just did this search: `msdn thread synchronization`, and the first hit was [Overview of synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives), which seems pretty appropriate for this.

Comment: For starters, don't try to modify the UI thread from another thread. That `.Invoke` blocks and isn't needed at all

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Is there a way to synchronize the changed values without using Invoke(Without modifying the UI thread)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview)

```
var _items = new BlockingCollection<string>(10); // 10 is max buffered items
void SendProc() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        _items.Add(i.ToString()); // blocks if more than 10 items not consumed
        Thread.Sleep(SEND_TIME_INTERVAL);
    }
    _items.CompleteAdding();
}
void ReceiveProc() {
    while (!_items.IsCompleted) {
        var item = _items.Take(); // blocks if _items empty
        // this.Invoke(...); // use item
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, with the exception of using the [`IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.iscompleted) property for controlling the execution flow. This property is not really intended for this purpose. The correct (and easy) way to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` is to use the `GetConsumingEnumerable` method.

Comment: @GraphWalk Thank you so much! The results are as follows:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lu0P956sHSjFzxdOyEpFRkipfGnjWBgt/view?usp=sharing